Gridded plane colouring problem. Can a 2x2 black square be created on a white gridded plane using 3x3 and 4x4 "stamps" that invert the grid colour?
Problem statement: All the squares on a gridded plane are colored white. We repeatedly perform the following operation: select any $3 \times 3$ or $4 \times 4$ square, then recolor each of its black squares to white and each white square to black. Is it possible, through a finite number of such operations, to achieve a configuration where the squares of a particular $2 \times 2$ square are black and all other squares are white?
I have been intrigued by this question. I suspect it is impossible but have difficulty proving it.
(It should be observed that the question is equivalent to erasing a black square from a white grid, but that hasn't really simplified the problem for me so far.)
Some attempts and observations thus far
Strategy 1 I thought that if we can show that the 1D analogue is impossible, i.e. given a white array of $1 \times 1$ squares, creating two adjacent black squares, using the operations of either inverting the colours of three or four adjacent squares. Given that we're dealing with squares in the original problem, clearly if the 1D case were shown to be impossible, that would imply the impossibility of the 2D case. But, alas the 1D case is possible.
As it happens I have found a solution on a torus, since it is relatively easy to show that we can reach the following configuration (1 for black, and 0 for white):
$$ 1\:\: 0\:\: 0\:\: 1 \\
0\:\: 0\:\: 0\:\: 0 \\
0\:\: 0\:\: 0\:\: 0 \\
1\:\: 0\:\: 0\:\: 1$$
It's not exactly a solution to the original question, but a fun observation nevertheless :)
Strategy 2 Perhaps we could just focus on a $4 \times 4$ grid and see what that implies. Note that reaching a configuration with a white $4 \times 4$ with a single black square in one of the corners would yield the desired result, since we could just join four such squares to create a the $2 \times 2$ black square. Similarly reaching a configuration of 2 adjacent black squares along any of the edges of a $4 \times 4$ square would do the trick. This includes the configuration of the $2 \times 2$ square anywhere inside the $4 \times 4$ square. I'm wondering if showing the impossibility of reaching such configurations within a $4 \times 4$ square wouldn't imply the impossibility of the general solution. Unfortunately those configurations are merely sufficient for the solution, but it's not obvious that they're necessary, so it's not so obvious this conjecture is true. But perhaps there is a key observation that I'm missing that would make this approach work?
Strategy 3 Or we could try yet another approach. If we show that the set of all $4 \times 4$ configurations achieved from the desired (final $2 \times 2$ black square) configuration is disjoint from the set of all $4 \times 4$ configurations achieved from the starting point (white grid), would that mean that the desired configuration is impossible?
I would appreciate any feedback -- method suggestions, strategy ideas, and insightful observations. If someone can solve it, that's great, but I will also accept an answer that will point to a tangible direction to solving the problem.

For a finite grid size, this is a Gaussian elimination problem over $\mathbb F_2$. Let's first check if small sizes are all impossible before trying to prove so.

Number the squares in $2×3$ pattern.
$$\begin{array}&1&2&3&1&2&3\\4&5&6&4&5&6\\1&2&3&1&2&3\\4&5&6&4&5&6\end{array}$$
The number of black $1s\pmod2$ equals the number of black $2s\pmod2$ equals the number of black $3s\pmod2$, and the same for $4,5$ and $6$.

Is this supposed to be an invariant that is unchanged by 4x4 and 3x3 moves but changed by a 2x2? I don't see how it is invariant under 3x3 as the middle row of a 3x3 changes the parities. Or did you intend something else?

It changes the parities of all three, so they remain equal.  The parity of $4,5,6$ can be different from the parity of $1,2,3$

Yes, a $3\times 3$ move keeps the parities of 1s, 2s and 3s all equal. A $4\times 4$ move doesn't change any of them, so they're still equal. But any $2\times 2$ move changes the parities of exactly two of them, breaking the triple equality. Very nice.

Ok, got it now. Nice!

One nitpick to this answer: I would change the phrasing from "the number of $1$s", "the number of $2$s", etc. to "the number of black $1$s", "the number of black $2$s", etc. (Obvisouly there are infinitely many squares with each number). I'd also change the first word from "color" to "number", to better distinguish the numbered labeling from the black/white status.

Can someone explain to me on this example what remains invariant? Any way I look at it there seems to be an issue after step 2. I suspect it's because I'm missing something.
Underlying pattern.
$$1 2 3 1 2 3 \
4 5 6 4 5 6 \
1 2 3 1 2 3 \
4 5 6 4 5 6 \$$
Starting state.
$$0 0 0 0 0 0 \
0 0 0 0 0 0 \
0 0 0 0 0 0 \
0 0 0 0 0 0 \$$
First 3x3 flip in top left corner.
$$1 1 1 0 0 0 \
1 1 1 0 0 0 \
1 1 1 0 0 0 \
0 0 0 0 0 0 \$$
Second 3x3 flip: columns 2,3,4, rows:2,3,4.
$$1 1 1 0 0 0 \
1 0 0 1 0 0 \
1 0 0 1 0 0 \
0 1 1 1 0 0 \$$

There are three $1$s, one $2$ and one $3$.  3,1,1 are all odd.  There are three $4$s, one $5$ and one $6$, and again those are all odd.

Thanks for the clarification.

Well.. it seems I am not the first to solve this one, but I'll still share my solution since the method works for a large range of other shapes than just squares.
We can look at the torus of 6x6 squares. We can basically view this torus as $F_2^{36}$, where we have a 1 for a black square, and a 0 for a white square. Our coloring action then basically becomes addition in this space. Our problem then becomes: is it possible to construct a specific vector in $F_2^{36}$ (one with four 1's in specific spots) as a linear combination of some set of vectors (in our case, we have two squares which can be in 36 spots, so 72 vectors).
One can solve this with for example some Python code:
import numpy as np
import galois

GF = galois.GF(2)

def solve_torus(N):
    #solve for a torus of size N
    A=[] #A[jN+k][] will contain the value of coordinate (j,k) in the i-th possible square
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(N):
            square3 = [0 for l in range(N**2)]
            for jj in range(3):
                for kk in range(3):
                    square3[N*((j+jj)%N)+((k+kk)%N)]=1
            A.append(square3)
            square4=[0 for l in range(N**2)]
            for jj in range(4):
                for kk in range(4):
                    square4[N*((j+jj)%N)+((k+kk)%N)]=1
            A.append(square4)
    B=[[j for j in i] for i in A]
    b = [0 for l in range(N ** 2)]
    b[0], b[1], b[N], b[N + 1] = 1, 1, 1, 1
    B.append(b)
    A=GF(A)
    B=GF(B)
    print(np.linalg.matrix_rank(A))
    print(np.shape(A))
    print(np.linalg.matrix_rank(B))
    print(np.shape(B)) #the two ranks will be different if there is no solution
solve_torus(6)

In this way we find that a 6x6 torus has no solutions.
In general, one can test multiple sizes of toruses, of course. If one specific torus has no solution, this implies that there is no solution on the entire grid. This is easy to see: for example for 6x6 toruses, one can divide the grid into x6 regions, and this gives rise to a torus: to the space with coordinate $(i,j)$ in the torus, we assign the value $(number-of-black-squares-with-coordinates-of-form-(6k+i,6l+j))\mod 2$. Switching colors of any square in the grid results in the same square being added in the torus. Hence any correct solution in the grid then has to correspond to a valid solution in the torus.
Final remark: If you take a 2x3 torus, you get the solution from Empy2
